# Make a whole row in a table "link-able"

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table

I have this code where the whole div is clickable and link to different URLS

jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=eBw8xooaHu

I want to make it work in a table and make the whole row clickable so I ended up to smth like this..

jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=bKRMP3bSl3

Is this manageable or I am looking to the wrong direction?

Comment: Please don't use JSFiddle collaboration links. If the code changes significantly later on, it may be difficult for future readers to follow.

Consider using [Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to use Jasny Bootstrap.

The way to add Jasny to your project its the same whit bootstrap.

Before import the libraries adding the next lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

after that add the class to your table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

and the tbody tag

```
<tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
```

on first td tag add the link whit a tag, td content pushed in to a tag. Like this:

```
<td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a></td>
```

if you desire its no show link in a td, then add to this td tag the class:

```
<td class="rowlink-skip">
```

when, your row link its now working at 100%.

References: [Jasny Bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/)

Sample: [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/j02md7pz/)

Answer (score -1):

Your fiddle links doesn't work, therefore I have to guess. If I wanted a table row to be clickable I would try to build it with an a-tag instead of a tr tag and use

```
table>a { display:table-row; }
```

for it.

```
<table>
    <a href="">
        <td></td>
    </a>
</table>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML, and the parser might do strange things trying to parse this. Most probably it will become `<a href=""></a><table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>`