# Turn HTML table into href link tabs

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, html-table

I have browsed through a few answers here on how to turn a HTML table row into a usable link. I could only find people aiming to do this -

```
<tr>
    <td width="15%"><a href="">Test3</a></td>
    <td><a href=""><b>Test1</b></a></td>
    <td><a href="">Test2</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Although that does work, it is obviously all separate links and not really what I am looking for. Call me fussy, but I am really trying to aim for something that works similar to the privileges page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

That is, the entire table row is a link, and no matter where you click, it will redirect. I'm not sure if I would need to use a HTML Table or some kind of List group? Any help would be great!

Comment: Why are you using tables? Unordered List or even floated DIVs would be a better solution.

Comment: I assumed it would work best for doing this but I'm not too sure what other options I have to achieve what I am looking for. Could you provide a small example if possible?

Comment: If you look at the source for the link you provided you will see SO is using a DIV structure.

Comment: Look this stack: [Stack Table link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694182/make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-link-able/41573766#41573766)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution is really the only way you can do this with HTML properly

```
<tr>
    <td width="15%"><a href="">Test3</a></td>
    <td><a href=""><b>Test1</b></a></td>
    <td><a href="">Test2</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Any other solution involves changing the table CSS

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding the href tag after the  like this:

```
<tr>
<a href="https://google.com">
    <td width="15%">Test3</a></td>
    <td><a href=""><b>Test1</b></a></td>
    <td><a href="">Test2</a></td>
</a>
  </tr>
```

This will make all the links clickable with the same URL. However, it wont look 100% like the privileges page since it has no style. Once you add CSS you should be able to achieve exactly what you want.